# Async-await seems to use the UI thread

Tags: wpf, async-await

In a view-model I use a factory:

```
private async Task<BaseData> InitializeAsync()
{
    await InstancesAsync();
    await ProjectsAsync();
    await AdminAsync();
    return this;
}
public static async Task<BaseData> CreateAsync()
{
    var ret = new BaseData();
    return await ret.InitializeAsync();
}
```

The awaited methods are rather staightforward, with e.g.

```
 var instances = await TaskEx.Run(new Func<List<string>>(() => Agent.GetInstances()));
```

In the wpf view I want to set the DataContext in the constructor:

```
Loaded += delegate
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(async () => { DataContext = await BasisGegevens.CreateAsync(); }));
};
```

Although it works, I feel rather uncomfortable because the UI thread is used *everywhere*, also after the callbacks when the awaits complete. What am I missing?

Also I don't understand how to use the factory pattern for the `DataContext` because without the `Invoke` above I get the error that a different thread owns the object.

EDIT: using the ideas of Mr. Cleary I get:

```
Loaded += async (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
          { DataContext = await BaseData.CreateAsync(); };
public static Task<BaseData> CreateAsync()
{
    var ret = new BaseData();
    return ret.InitializeAsync();
}
private async Task<BaseData> InitializeAsync()
{
    // UI thread here
    await InstancesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // thread 'a' here
    await ProjectsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // thread 'a' sometimes 'b' here
    await AdminAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // thread 'a' or 'b' here
    return this;
}
```

This works fine, except I cannot understand how `ConfigureAwait(false)` works.
Inside the method `InstancesAsync()` I have the awaited task:
`var instances = await TaskEx.Run(new Func<List<string>>(() => Agent.GetInstances()));`
After awaiting the repsonse, I return in the UI thread - I never expected that to happen!
Note that `ProjectsAsync()` and `AdminAsync()` behave the same, although they start on a worker (or background) thread!
I thougth that `ConfigureAwait(true)` has the effect of returning in the calling thread (in my case UI thread). I tested that and it is so.
Why do I see this with `ConfigureAwait(false)` too: because of a nested await, see comments.

Comment: What is the source of the `Loaded` event in the code you showed? If this is a regular [`FrameworkElement.Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event, it should be fired on the UI thread. Are you creating a view on a separate thread? Is that perhaps because you're calling `Agent.GetInstances()` on a non-UI pool thread?

Comment: The Loaded event is a regular FrameworkElement.Loaded event. I intended to create the view on the UI thread, that apparantly was wrong. Agent.GetInstances() runs in an awaited task, I expected it to be on a non-UI pool thread, but it wasn't.

Comment: `TaskEx.Run` does use a separate pool thread to run your `Func` delegate, that's where `Agent.GetInstances()` is executed. I'd suggest you follow Stephen's answer and make sure both WPF UI elements and ViewModel objects are all created on the same - UI - thread. Add some logging (`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`) to see what thread you're on and where.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` only affects that specific `await`, it has no effect on `await`s that are “inside” it.

Comment: @svick: of course, thanks, I also checked it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it most useful to treat the ViewModel as having UI thread affinity. Think of it as the logical UI, even if it's not the *actual* UI. So all property and observable collection updates on ViewModel classes should be done on the UI thread.

In your `async` methods, if you don't need to return to the UI thread, then you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid resuming on the UI thread. For example, if your various initialization methods are independent, you could do something like this:

```
private async Task<BaseData> InitializeAsync()
{
  // Start all methods on the UI thread.
  var instancesTask = InstancesAsync();
  var projectsTask = ProjectsAsync();
  var adminTask = AdminAsync();

  // Await for them all to complete, and resume this method on a background thread.
  await Task.WhenAll(instancesTask, projectsTask, adminTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

  return this;
}
```

Also, any time you have `return await`, take another look to see if you can just avoid `async`/`await` entirely:

```
public static Task<BaseData> CreateAsync()
{
  var ret = new BaseData();
  return ret.InitializeAsync();
}
```

Finally, you should strongly avoid `Dispatcher`. Your `Loaded` event could be simplified to this:

```
Loaded += async ()
{
  DataContext = await BasisGegevens.CreateAsync();
};
```

Comment: I derived `return await` from your factory pattern at 'http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html'.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` : the tasks have to run in determined order.

Comment: The Loaded delegate I must write as `async (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` for it to compile.